# How to play multiple animations back-to-back in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

I can not play several animations one after the other with a "fluid" effect:

```css
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    animation: zoomIn 1s, pulse 0.5s ease 1s;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
  }

@keyframes pulse {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I want to keep the keyframes separate.

Comment: Define "fluid effect".

Comment: Please clarify how you want your code to behave and how it currently falls short of that.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to consider `forwards` on the second one to keep its last state because actually when both animations ends your element get back to the inital value of the scale transform which is `scale(1)` *(to be more precise it's `transform:none`)*

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  animation: zoomIn 1s, pulse 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

The waiting time is due to the `animation-timing-function` used which is `ease` for both and this mean that you will have an ease-out (slow at the end) and ease-in (slow at the start) which create this behavior of *pausing* between both animations. If you change the first one to `ease-in` and the last one to `ease-out` you won't have this issue.

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  animation: zoomIn 1s ease-in, pulse 0.5s ease-out 1s forwards;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the pause time between the two animations, even if the second animation is playing quickly, we see very briefly a stop between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Your pulse animation ends at scale 1.1, and then your circle snaps back to scale 1. Maybe the pulse keyframes should be as follows:

```
@keyframes pulse {
        from {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        50% {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
}
```

In the snippet below you see no snapping, but maybe this isn't the effect you were looking for?

```css
#circle {
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: red;
   animation: zoomIn 1s, pulse 0.5s ease 1s;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
  }

  @keyframes zoomIn {
   0% {
    transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
    transform: scale(1);
   }
  }

  @keyframes pulse {
   from {
    transform: scale(1);
   }
   50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
   }
      100% {
         transform: scale(1);
      }
  }
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a short pulse at the end when your circle is scaled to 1, this is your fluid effect I presume.
Rather than having to different animations, why don't we tweak the keyframes in the zoomIn animation a little bit.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    animation: zoomIn 0.4s ease-out;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

the only animation is 'Transform', it is best to use a 'timing function' customization, I recommend utilities 'Cubic-bezier' go to this website http://cubic-bezier.com and practice. read before something about bezier curve.

```css
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    animation: zoomIn 1s cubic-bezier(.4,.17,.49,1.54);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

UPDATE

or this other 'timing-function'

```css
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    animation: zoomIn 1.5s cubic-bezier(.56,1,.92,.7);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* */
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```